# NSURLError: the network connection was lost

Tags: iphone

Can someone help me understanding and resolving this error I am getting when connecting to web service:

NSURLError is: Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost."
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://username:password@..org:443/zws/xmlrpc/restricted1/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://username:password@..org:443/zws/xmlrpc/restricted1/,
NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., NSUnderlyingError=0x5f2b300 "The network connection was lost.

Comment: Simulator or device?  Might want to re-do your network settings on whatever is running your code.

Comment: Simulator, network is connected as I can use other web service